# Strange Issue with Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am having a very strange issue with Socket.IO.  For some reason, it appears that the emit "buffer" is being duplicated over and over, as every connection results in n+1 replies:

```
COM.ping();
undefined
0 "CONNECTION STATUS: OK - 0" app.js:9
COM.ping();
undefined
1 "CONNECTION STATUS: OK - 1" app.js:9
2 "CONNECTION STATUS: OK - 1" app.js:9
COM.ping();
undefined
3 "CONNECTION STATUS: OK - 2" app.js:9
4 "CONNECTION STATUS: OK - 2" app.js:9
5 "CONNECTION STATUS: OK - 2" app.js:9
COM.ping();
undefined
6 "CONNECTION STATUS: OK - 3" app.js:9
7 "CONNECTION STATUS: OK - 3" app.js:9
8 "CONNECTION STATUS: OK - 3" app.js:9
9 "CONNECTION STATUS: OK - 3" app.js:9
COM.ping();
undefined
10 "CONNECTION STATUS: OK - 4" app.js:9
11 "CONNECTION STATUS: OK - 4" app.js:9
12 "CONNECTION STATUS: OK - 4" app.js:9
13 "CONNECTION STATUS: OK - 4" app.js:9
14 "CONNECTION STATUS: OK - 4" app.js:9
```

The code for this is fairly simple.  On the client:

```
    this.ping = function(){
        socket.on('PING__',function (data){
            console.log(count++,"CONNECTION STATUS: "+$(data)[0].status);
            data = '';
        });
        socket.emit('__PING');
    }
```

On the Server:

```
    var counter = 0;
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('__PING', function (data) {
            socket.emit('PING__' , {status:'OK - '+counter++});
        });
    });
```

So, for some reason, when I attempt to ping, it is somehow reiterating.  I'm not sure why.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Really stupid logic error:

```
 this.ping = function(){
        socket.on('PING__',function (data){
            console.log(count++,"CONNECTION STATUS: "+$(data)[0].status);
            data = '';
        });
        socket.emit('__PING');
    }
```

Should have been:

```
var events = {};
this.ping = function(){
    if(typeof events.ping === 'undefined'){
        events.ping = socket.on('PING__',function (data){
            console.log("CONNECTION STATUS: "+$(data)[0].status);
            data = '';
        });
    }
    socket.emit('__PING');
}
```

It was messing up because I was binding the event handler over and over lol.